# create a vote in telegram with a large describing text

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to create a vote in telegram messenger.
I wrote a text about 1000 characters as "question" but the "vote bot" kept only the first lines and some part of my question got lost.
Does anyone have a suggestion to keep all of the text in the "question"?
Thank you so much ;)

Comment: Try to text it in private chat, but remind that this site is for _programming questions_, not for this kind of questions.

Comment: thank you for your notation.where should I ask such questions?

Comment: Ask to Telegram official support.